# Execute a dynamic method using eval or public_send

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have these code that executes a dynamic method. I'm using `eval` here to execute it but what I wanted to do is changed it to `public_send` because I was told so and it's much safer.

Current code:

```
  # update workstep logic here.
        incoming_status = params[params[:name]]

        # grab workflow, this is current data, use this to compare status to in comming status
        workflow = get_workorder_product_workstep(params[:workflow_id])

        # check current status if its pending allow to update
        # security concern EVAL!
       
        if eval("workflow.can_#{incoming_status}?")
          # update status
          eval("workflow.#{incoming_status}")
          # updated attribute handled_by
          workflow.update_attributes(handled_by_id: @curr_user.id)
          workflow.save
        else
          flash[:notice] = 'Action not allowed'
        end
```

The `eval` here is the concern. How can I changed this to `public_send`?

Here's what I did.

`public_send("workflow.can_#{incoming_status}?")`

`public_send("#{workflow}.can_#{incoming_status}?")`

both of them doesn't work. gives me an error of no method. The first public error returns this `undefined method workflow.can_queue? for #<Spree::Admin::WorkordersController:0x00007ff71c8e6f00>`

But it should work because I have a method `workflow.can_queue?`

the second error on  public is this
`undefined method #<Spree::WorkorderProductWorkstep:0x00007ff765663550>.can_queue? for #<Spree::Admin::WorkordersController:0x00007ff76597f798>`

I think for the second `workflow` is being evaluated separately? I'm not sure.

Comment: I think you want something closer to `workflow.public_send("can_#{incoming_status}?")` for your `if` statement. For what's inside the if, it would follow a similar pattern `workflow.public_send(incoming_status)`

Comment: "it should work because I have a method `workflow.can_queue`?" Do you really have a method with *that exact name*? Including the dot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working with `public_send` you can change the relevant lines to:

```
if workflow.public_send("can_#{incoming_status}?")
  # update status
  workflow.public_send(incoming_status.to_s)
    # ...
```

**A note about security and risks**

`workflow.public_send("can_#{xyz}?")` can only call methods on `workflow` that are `public` and which start with the prefix `can_` and end with `?`. That is probably only a small number of methods and you can easily decide if you want to allow all those methods.

`workflow.public_send("#{incoming_status'})` is different because it allows all public methods on `workflow` – even `destroy`. That means using this without the `"can_#{incoming_status}?"` is probably a bad idea. Or you should at least first check if `incoming_status` is in a whitelist of allowed methods.

`eval` is the worst because it will evaluate the whole string without any context (e.q. an object like `workflow`). Imaging you have `eval("workflow.#{incoming_status}")` without to check first if `incoming_status` is actually allowed. If someone then sends an `incoming_status` like this `"to_s; system('xyz')"`then `xyz` could be everything – like commands to send a hidden file via email, to install a backdoor or to delete some files.

Comment: thank you sir. It worked. can you tell me the security risk on this one? or maybe a link? read few blogs but doesnt address the security risk behind it. they said its just a security risk. I know this is like hte `eval` on javascript that runs a script on the fly. just wondering if there are other deep reasons. thank you again.

Comment: @artoo I updated my answer to address your question regarding security.

Comment: thank you sir. appreciate it. I was thinking of refactoring this but its hard not to use either. I have not whitelisted any method too. I might do that. thank you again.